# Divide verb in Cobol

Tags: cobol

I have this odd output in the remainder part of the DIVIDE verb in COBOL.
The goal is just to divide 213.20 by 10 then save-off the quotient to another variable as well as the remainder. I was expecting in the remainder part to have value of 3.2 but it just gave me 0. Please enlighten me.

See code snippet below:

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 VAR-A  PIC S9(09)V99 COMP-3 VALUE 213.20
    01 VAR-B  PIC S9(09)V99 COMP-3 VALUE 10.00
    01 VAR-C  PIC S9(09)V99 COMP-3 VALUE 0.
    01 VAR-D  PIC S9V99     COMP-3 VALUE 0.  

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-PARAGRAPH.
    DIVIDE VAR-A
      BY VAR-B
      GIVING VAR-C
      REMAINDER VAR-D.

    DISPLAY 'VAR-A: 'VAR-A.
    DISPLAY 'VAR-B: 'VAR-B.
    DISPLAY 'VAR-C: 'VAR-C.
    DISPLAY 'VAR-D: 'VAR-D.
********************************************
RESULTS:

VAR-A: 00000021320
VAR-B: 00000001000
VAR-C: 00000002132
VAR-D: 000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined the receiving variable `VAR-C` with 2 digits after the decimal. I think you wanted integer division, so try defining it as follows:

```
01 VAR-C    PIC S9(09) COMP-3.
```

Now `VAR-C` can only hold whole numbers (eg. 21) and the remainder (`VAR-D`) will contain the residual (eg. 3.20)

Answer (score 1):

This might help, somebody had a similar problem:

http://www.ibmmainframes.com/about44677.html

Answer (score 1):

I have seen strange results in the past if your remainder PIC does not match the divisor PIC. Change your remainder to PIC S9(9)V99 and post the results.

Comment: As long as the magnatude of the Remainder is at least that of the
Divisor and the precision of the Remainder is at least that of the Dividend and
Divisor, the Remainder will be accurate. In the OP's case these conditions
were met. The problem was that the Divisor had a precision equal to the Dividend
leaving a zero Remainder. If precision/magnatude requirements have been
met, the following equalities apply: `Dividend / Divisor = Quotient + Remainder` and
`Quotient * Divisor + Remainder = Dividend`. If this relationship fails, there is
a precision/magnatude mismatch in one or more variables.